RxJs interval sums up the time since the previous interval
The logic is this: when mounting or changing a mod, a timer starts. It should reset if there is an active call, and if the user clicks. If there is no activity, the mod changes, but the timer continues to work. There is a problem with resetting the timer by a user click. In practice, the behavior is as follows: when clicking, the timer is postponed and does not work, but the next time if there is no activity, the mod changes after the timer time + the time from the beginning of the previous timer to the click.
For example, the timer works every 10 seconds, when mounting, the timer is initialized, I click after 3 seconds from the beginning, when 10 seconds pass (there was no more activity) the mod does not change (this is correct), but now without activity the mod will change only after 13 seconds.
What is the error?
P.S. I am from Russia, sorry for the grammar :)
const idleTimerEpic: Epic<AnyAppState, AnyAction, EpicDeps> = (action$, state$) => {
  const idleTimeout = 45000;

  const events = ['mousedown', 'ontouchstart'];
  const signal$ = merge(...events.map(event => fromEvent(document, event))).pipe(
    startWith(null),
    map(_ => Date.now()),
  );

  const isClientFromInternet = isFromNetworkConnection();
  /**
   * Если клиент работает из сети то игнорим это
   * чтобы не создавать споров кто прав и кто что автоматически сбросил
   */
  if (isClientFromInternet) {
    console.log('Sorry but we can not reset mode because you from Internet');

    return EMPTY;
  }

  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(modeUpdateAction.init.type, lifeCircleActions.mount.type),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return interval(idleTimeout).pipe(
        takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(modeUpdateAction.init.type, lifeCircleActions.mount.type))),
        withLatestFrom(state$, signal$),
        filter(
          // если есть текущий звонок или пользовательская активность, то пропускаем
          ([, state, lastClickTime]) => {
            if (getCallState(state) !== CALL_STATE.none) {
              return false;
            }

            return !(Date.now() - lastClickTime < idleTimeout);
          },
        ),
        // иначе выходим в МГН режим
        mergeMap(() => {
          return of(modeUpdateAction.reset());
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
};


You are trying to create what is called debouncing. There is a special operator for this in rxjs. All you have to do is rewrite your code above to something like this:
const idleTimerEpic: Epic<AnyAppState, AnyAction, EpicDeps> = (action$, state$) => {
    const isClientFromInternet = isFromNetworkConnection();
    /**
     * Если клиент работает из сети то игнорим это
     * чтобы не создавать споров кто прав и кто что автоматически сбросил
     */
    if (isClientFromInternet) {
        console.log('Sorry but we can not reset mode because you from Internet');
        return EMPTY;
    }
    
    const idleTimeout = 45000;
    const events = ['mousedown', 'ontouchstart'];
    const signal$ = merge(...events.map(event => fromEvent(document, event)));

    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(modeUpdateAction.init.type, lifeCircleActions.mount.type),
        switchMap(() => signal$),
        startWith(null),
        debounceTime(idleTimeout),
        map(() => modeUpdateAction.reset()),
    );
}

Also, I have created a sandbox for you to see working solution with debounce: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rxjs-playground-forked-5zljmk
